# sending mail using pear

Tags: php

I have installed pear and when sending mail, I get the following error: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 6144 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\GamesRus\mail.php on line 2

I am running on windows 7. Here is my code:

```
$mail = Mail::factory("mail");

$headers = array("From"=>"me@example.com", "Subject"=>"Test Mail");

$body = "This is a test!";

$mail->send("jngichabe@yahoo.com", $headers, $body);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something in your script is using up RAM memory, so you're hitting the server limit of RAM usage (128 MB in your case). Try to find out what part of your code it is that's using so much memory.

Can it be that you have a large body, or trying to attach a really large file to the e-mail message?